# remove htmlspecialchars?

Tags: php

Do i use htmlspecialchars on `$_GET['search']` on page2?  Wouldn't i have to remove the htmlspecialchars from `$_GET['search']` on page3 before i add `mysql_real_escape_string` to the variable?  If so.. how do i remove htmlspecialchars?

page1

```
 $searchterm = "test"; //users search term
echo "<a href='page2?seach=test'>test</test>";
```

page2

```
$var = htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']);
<form action='page3' method='post'><input type='text' name='test' value='$var' /><input type='submit' value='submit'/></form>
```

page3

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['test']);
//insert into mysql database
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do i use htmlspecialchars on `$_GET['search']` on page2?

You use `htmlspecialchars` when you have some *text* and are about to output it as *HTML*.

That is what you are doing in your second example, so yes, you would.

> Wouldn't i have to remove the htmlspecialchars from `$_GET['search']` on page3

No. The HTML is parsed by the browser to produce a text value.

(This also means that browsers do not submit HTML-safe data, so when you take the data **out** of the database then you would use `htmlspecialchars` before outputting it to an HTML document).

> before i add `mysql_real_escape_string` to the variable

Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string`, [use prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/19068).

Comment: ok... so if i were to output $_GET['search'] as HTML on page3 i would have to use htmlspecialchars again?

Comment: Yes. It is text data, so you convert it to HTML before outputting it to an HTML document.